# How to change the text of "x= y= " in the bottom of the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib` in order to display 2D plot (longitude vs altitude).

As you can see in the attached print screen, in the right bottom of the plot, we can see the text "`x= XXX y= YYY`" (the place of mouse in the plot axis).

[image]

How can I change this text to "`LONG = XXX LAT = YYY`" ?

Comment: check this out https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html

Comment: And some further help here: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html

Comment: You have to re-define `axes.format_coord` function: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_zcoord.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-image-zcoord-py